# Python logical test of odd numbers

Tags: python, comparison, logical-operators

I wonder if my answer below is correct and feasible or are there any improvements Thank you.
question: a program that checks x y and z if they are odd or even if they are odd checks if the number is the biggest of all three.
Below my answer:

```
    x = 4
    y = 7
    z = 9

  #first condition where 3 numbers are all odd.

    if x%2 == 1 and y%2 == 1 and z%2 == 1:
        if x > y and x > z:
            print "x is the biggest odd number."
        elif x > y and z > x:
            print "z is the biggest odd number."
        else:
            print "y is the biggest odd number."

#second condition where 2 of the numbers are odd
elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 1 and z%2 == 1:
    if y > z:
        print "y is the biggest odd number."
    else:
        print "y is the biggest odd number."
elif x%2 == 1 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 1:
    if x > z:
        print "x is the biggest odd number."
    else:
        print "z is the biggest odd number."

elif x%2 == 1 and y%2 == 1 and z%2 == 0:
    if x > y:
        print "x is the biggest odd number."
    else:
        print "y is the biggest odd number."    

#third condition where only one of the numbers is odd.

elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 1:
    print "z is the biggest odd number."
elif x%2 == 1 and y%2 == 0 and z%2 == 0:
    print "x is the biggest odd number."
elif x%2 == 0 and y%2 == 1 and z%2 == 0:
    print "y is the biggest odd number."

#last condition if none of the numer are odd or not numbers.

else:
    print " None of the numbers are odd or not a number."
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be good at http://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow! That is a ton of code. Why don't you just put `x`,`y`,`z` in a list. Use a list comprehension to remove even numbers. Then select the maximum value using the max function. Something like this

```
arr = [x,y,z]
arr = [i for i in arr if i%2!=0] #select only odd numbers
print(max(arr)) #display the maximum number
```

Then you can use `max(arr)` to figure out  what variable contains the maximum odd number.

Comment: uh, no I guess. He needs to print 'x','y' or 'z'.

Comment: @PyNEwbie he probably will. but still doesn't meet his exact specifications though.

Comment: if arr is empty due to no odd numbers, the print statement produces ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Comment: @Totem I don't think a call to `print` can raise that exception.

Comment: @EricUrban I used your idea and built it into a dictionary to support printing 'x','y' and 'z'. Hope that's okay with you :) Although this is thus limited to x,y and z. Any suggestions?

Also @Totem is right. I checked. It does raise that exception. You could do `print(max(arr) if arr else 'No odd numbers')`

Comment: @Sabyasachi No, `print` doest not raise that exception. The call to `max` does.

Comment: @EricUrban yeah I know that. I am just saying you can avoid that exception without too much extra code. :D

Comment: @EricUrban Well ok, but that particular print statement holds the possible culprit :)

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is probably a bit too verbose and specific. What if you needed to find the largest odd number and there were four? Or a hundred?

A better idea would be to use Python's [max](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function to examine a sequence that filters out even numbers.

You can collect the numbers to be examined in a sequence like a [list](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#lists):

```
A = [53, 31, 59, 75, 25, 32, 99, 15, 63, 35]
```

Then you can filter that sequence with a list comprehension:

```
A_odd = [n for n in A if n % 2 != 0]
```

Then you can find the max of that sequence:

```
max_odd = max(A_odd)
```

Suppose that there were no odd numbers in the sequence, though. The `max` function raises an exception if its argument is empty. So we can use a conditional expression to check to see if `A_odd` is empty:

```
if A_odd:
    max_odd = max(A_odd)
else:
    max_odd = "No odd numbers in sequence"
```

Then when we print the answer with `print(A_odd)` we get the result or the message.

Python 3.4 (not yet released) includes an addition to the max function that allows this to be even more compact - you can skip the conditional and just do `max(A_odd, default="No odd numbers in sequence")`

Answer (score 2):

This is inspired by Eric's answer but meets your need to print x, y and z instead of values.

```
>>>val={'x':x,'y':y,'z':z}
>>>newval=dict(k,d for k,d in val.items() if d%2==1)
```

Personally I would prefer to write `if d%2` but that's just me, it's up to you.

```
>>>if newval:
          print(max(newval.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]),'is maximum')
   else:
          print('No odd numbers')
```

It uses a dictinoary with Eric's list comprehension idea.

**EDIT**: I just figured that this would be cooler using a function.

```
>>>def findmax(**x):
   new=dict((k,d) for k,d in x.items() if d%2)
   if new:
       print(max(new.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]),'is maximum')
   else:
       print('No odd numbers')
```

Test run like so,

```
>>>findmax(x=1,y=37,z=208,a=193)
(a,193) is maximum
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = x, y, z

try:
    print max([n for n in nums if n%2 == 1])
except ValueError:
    print 'No odd numbers'
```

This prints `'No odd numbers'` if there are none  in `nums`

Doing `print(max(some_list))` where `some_list` is empty returns an error and so is not dealing with situations where there are no odd numbers present

Comment: You should probably catch `ValueError` and not every possible exception, yes?